# How to remove null text on the screen in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I build an app in which there are two pages(screens),the first page receives the data from second page.But the problem is that before getting the data from second page it is showing "null" on the first page screen.Below are the codes of these two pages.Note:The first page screen is the main launcher screen.

> First Page

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  String value;
  MyHomePage({Key key,this.value}):super(key:key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Flutter"),
      ),
      body:Center(
       child:new Text("${widget.value}")      )
}
```

> Second Page

```
class _List extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyList(),
    );
  }
}
class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyListState createState() => _MyListState();
}

class _MyListState extends State<MyList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text("List"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0,top: 20.0,right: 5.0),
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                var route=new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=>new MyHomePage(value: "Apple",),
                );
                Navigator.of(context).push(route);
              },
              child: new Card(
                child:
                new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text('Apple'),
                    new Text('Banana')
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
 );
  }
}
```

Comment: By looking at your code looks like `MyHomePage` is actually the first screen to be called on launch which won't have the String (`value`) since you don't pass it on the  `home: MyHomePage()`. If you don't want it to be `null` just give it `MyHomePage(value: "Something")`. But to me looks like you are misleading the app flow because I can't see a way in your example to actually go to the `MyList` screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a blank Container() widget instead of Text() widget like the code below :

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Flutter"),
    ),
    body:Center(
        child: widget.value==null ? Container() : new Text("${widget.value}")
      )
    );
  }
}
```